# prevent SERPS from other subdomains (locales) appearing in a specific region

Tags: seo, internationalization, multi-subdomains

What is the best practise to prevent SERPS from other subdomains (locales) appearing in a specific region.

For instance a search in CA should only return pages from the subdomain ca.example.com and not from other locales such as uk.example.com.

I know of the hreflang attr but are there other measures to prevent/block subdomains from other regions competing.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Structured Data Properties **[Organization](http://schema.org/Organization)** or **[LocalBusiness](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness)** (Use the most specific LocalBusiness sub-type possible; for example, Restaurant, DaySpa, HealthClub, and so on). 
According to **[Guide to Local Businesses of Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-businesses)**:

> *For a business with sub-departments, each with its own distinct properties such as opening hours or telephone numbers, you can mark up the **department** property with an element for each sub-department. Define properties that differ from the main store individually in each respective department element.*

Also these properties have the following elements suitable for localization and for the attitude of the main office and branches: **address** + **containedInPlace** +  **containsPlace** + **location** + **parentOrganization** + **subOrganization**